# Nexux 10 emulator/avd not running/starting

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am trying to create the Android emulator for Nexus 10 using latest [ADT](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adt.html) (21) and SDK tools. I have the below configurations for Nexus 10 AVD.

```
Screen Size - 10 inches
Resolution - 2560 X 1600
Screen Size - xlarge
Screen Density - Xhdpi
Screen ratio - long
```

RAM - 512 (Not able to set 1024 emulator crash)

But once AVD is created, it does not load Android; it just shows a black screen. My system is 32 bit [Intel Core i3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Core#Core_i3) with 4 GB RAM.

Comment: Windows? Have you tried to execute your avd with administrator privileges? Open a command as administrator and, inside your android-sdk/tools folder enter the follow code: emulator -avd YourAVD

Comment: I am logged in as administrator. Tried using command line as well but seems same results.

Comment: cmd always run as normal user for default. You should explicitly run it as administrator.

Comment: Showing the error as Renderer error: failed to create/resize pbuffer!!

Comment: Have you tried to update your video drivers?

Comment: Sorry not working, Tried updating drivers but Microsoft say they are already up to date.

Comment: try with another values of memory (in MB): 

    "emulator.exe -memory 512 -avd YourAVD" 

Another option is create the AVD using x86 as CPU (I guess taget 4.0 has this CPU option).

Comment: Another guess... "emulator.exe -gpu on -memory 512 -avd YourAVD" or "emulator.exe -gpu off -memory 512 -avd YourAVD"

Comment: Tried with all the options but no effects. Thanks for all the efforts man..

Comment: Try and set *Use Host GPU* option when creating AVD. Please see [my answer to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13581548/android-how-to-create-android-emulator-for-nexus10/14153527#14153527).

Comment: @Krishnabhadra Use Host GPU  option worked for me, you should answer this :) thnx for the link

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with monitor, LCD (or any other display device you are using) or graphic card.
Nexus 10 has gigantic screen density, how could it be displayed or replicated on a lower screen density screen. 
Edit on proposal of

- Krishnabhadra

To get it working you must match your screen resolution with the scale-down resolution of the emulator. Before running an emulator a dialog-window appears in which its ask the user to set emulator screen size and pixel ratio (screen density scaled to the display device). Make sure you select the current screen resolution.

Comment: This is wrong.. See my answer in the duplicate question..

Comment: Theres a similar answer on two more similar question. @Krishnabhadra. My answer is not to question "How to make a Nexus 10 emulator" but its to reason why black screen is shown and in that sense its right. Hope you understand my point

Comment: By the way thanks for correction!