# Android : How to Create Android Emulator for Nexus10?

Tags: android, android-emulator, emulation

I am trying to create the android emulator for Nexus 10 using latest ADT(21) and SDK tools. I have the following configuration for the Nexus 10 AVD:

```
Screen Size - 10 inches 
Resolution - 2560 X 1600 
Screen Size - xlarge Screen Density - Xhdpi 
Screen ratio - long
RAM - 1024
```

Let me know if this configuration is wrong. After creating the above Configuration I was able to create the AVD but couldn't load it. It only shows a black screen. What could be the problem here?

I am Using Ubuntu 11.10.

Comment: Settings are correct as it is xlarge-xhdpi. I guess the problem comes from somewhere else. Does your emulator work for another AVD?

Comment: @shkschneider :Thnks for your support.My emulator runs well in all other Configuration except above configuration.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

I had the same issue. You can do one thing,

1) When you create AVD, make sure **Use Host GPU** option is checked.

[image]

It worked for me, in my Mac OS X Mountain Lion 10.8.2, and eclipse juno.

EDIT : Sorry folks for  the confusion. There is no Google Nexus 10 skin (at the time of writing this). What you see in the image is a Nexus 10 equalant I created using Device Definition (AVD manager 2nd tab) feature of eclipse. It is just I named it as **Nexus 10** and it is not default google emulator.

Comment: How did you get Nexus 10 skin. I couldn't find one in Android Platforms. Can you please advice. Thanks in advance

Comment: Shouldn't the screen density be xxhdpi?

Comment: This also works using "Intel Atom (x86)" for the CPU/ABI if you're using the Intel HAXM accelerator, contradicting some of the other posts saying ARM(armeabi) is required

Comment: This works but I can't take screenshots from the emulator... Must be related to this http://stackoverflow.com/q/10022580/369317 So it seems to be impossible to take a screenshot from nexus 10 emulator at the moment...

Answer (score 6):

I think the **monitor resolution is more important than the hardware** of your computer. I have a PC i7 & 16GB RAM under Windows 7, with two DELL monitor 1920x1080 and it is imposible to run Nexus 10 emulator. This computer runs Nexus 7 emulator perfectly.

But my less powerfull iMac i5 & 8 GB RAM under OSX Mountain Lion, runs perfectly Nexus 10 AVD.

I have tried with/without **use host gpu** option, and only work when it is **checked**.

I have tried to emulate other devices like Samsung Galaxy S4 and it happens the same!

By the way, it is recomended to specify low value RAM and SD Card values for performance (512MB & 16-96MB).

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue (have, actually). It is quite simple, the resolution and the screen density are just too high for your monitor (on that screen size), so it cannot display it. - I am sure your emulator runs perfectly on other configurations

Comment: This is wrong.. I am able to run it in low resolution screens. I tried it on low resolution/dencity monitor and had no problem. Please see my answer

Comment: @Krishnabhadra: I had tried your solution but it doesn't work. Could you please see my question once http://stackoverflow.com/q/18670382/1665507 ? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is the correct configuration for an Nexus 10 `Android Virtual Device`:

[image: Nexus10_AVD]

Your `screensize` and `density` was wrong.

> **Screen Size** - 10.1 inches 
>  **Resolution** - 2560x1600 
>   **Size** - xlarge 
>  **Density** - xxhdpi 
>  
>   **Screen Ratio** - long 
>  **RAM** - 2048 MiB

Comment: I'm curious about your screenshot, what soft/mod is it? :)

Comment: @AlixBloom Arch Linux, with awesome WM and Solarized Dark theme. It must be still somewhere on my harddrive, I can upload it for you, if you want.

Comment: Using 2GB RAM , VM Heap: 128, Internal Storage: 512 MB, SD Card 500 MB and Use Host GPU true, its working super fine in Windows PC... :D

Answer (score 1):

One more way is to use new

> Genymotion Android Emulator

It is available for Ubuntu also , have a look at my [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18779975/877994) for other info related to it.

Answer (score 0):

With IntelliJ you need to open tools - android - AVD manager  and then when you add a new AVD try ensuring that your CPU/ABI is set to ARM(armeabi)   Had some trouble before like this and it was down to this setting.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thnk for your Support. but in my case CPU/ABI is already set to ARM(armeabi) though it continuously showing black screen.