# Eclipse AVD Nexus 5 emulator not working

Tags: android, eclipse, android-virtual-device

I'm trying to run a nexus 5 emulator in Eclipse AVD but I get a blank screen, I tried Nexus 4 emulation and it works fine, but not Nexus 5 for some reason. I tried this on multiple computers.

This is just running an emulator with no project, so it's not a code issue.

Please advise.
Thanks

Answer (score 20):

I had the same issue. You probably have no skin defined. Adding a skin, such as WVGA800, solved this for me.

Comment: I was using "skin with dynamic hardware controls", moving it to WVGA800 made it work.

Answer (score 1):

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13581548/android-how-to-create-android-emulator-for-nexus10) out. You might find something similar.

You should try lowering ram of the AVD if you don't have enough in your pc to support the created avd

By the way I have never managed to make the nexus 10 AVD work in my laptop. It needs a stronger machine probably

edit

[too much ram probably](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22597781/an-android-virtual-device-that-failed-to-load)