# Android Nexus 10 Emulator not running properly

Tags: android, android-emulator, nexus-10

I know this question  is a duplicate to the following,

[Android : How to Create Android Emulator for Nexus10?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13581548/android-how-to-create-android-emulator-for-nexus10?rq=1)

[Nexux 10 emulator/avd not running/starting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13533516/nexux-10-emulator-avd-not-running-starting)

I have set the below configuration,

```
Screen Size - 10 inches
Resolution - 2560 X 1600
Screen Size - xlarge
Screen Density - Xhdpi
Screen ratio - long
```

My system configuration is,

```
Intel Core i3 processor
4GB Ram
Windows 7(32 bit)
Monitor resolution-1366*768
```

I had tried those answers and set accordingly but no luck.Even I scaled down the screen size .AVD runs and shows `"Emulator not responding "` message and then I was forced to close the AVD.

Can't I run Nexus 10 AVD for the above configuration system? Any help and guidance will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Tried that config on my system. It ran very slow and I have a i5 with 8GB on Win 7 64 bit with a 1680x1050 screen. I am also using HAXM (http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager). I needed to set the AVD memory to 512MB. The high AVD screen resolution and Windows memory management  doesn't work for this config.

Comment: @GR8DAN: Thanks for you valuable comment buddy.Does that mean, I can't run the Nexus 10 AVD for the above configuration?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about this message - "Emulator not responding" ,

but you can try new `Genymotion Android Emulator`, have a look at it , it is faster and you can resize it.

Below configuration is available in list of virtual devices.

> WXGA 10.1" Tablet - 4.2.2 API 17 - 1280*800 Genymotion Virtual Device - 160dpi (MDPI)

you can change the screen density after creation of Virtual Device

FYI : Genymotion Android Emulator is an alternate way to Google Android Emulator.

Comment: Take a look at Genymotion's licensing before you start. The Free version is actually limited to personal use only.

Answer (score 0):

To make the Nexus 10 AVD work, you need to set the AVD memory to something higher, try 512mb.

Comment: Yes buddy I had already given 512mb memory with "Use Host GPU" checked.

Comment: No buddy it didn't worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

if you didn't depend on ARM CPU, try genymotion.